# create Magento package in packagist

Tags: magento2, composer, package, github

I am trying to require my package newly setup in packagist and github in a magento local projet when I run command.

```
composer require anasstouaticoder/magento2-module-instantconfigurationcopy
```

but I am getting this error message

[InvalidArgumentException]
Could not find a version of package anasstouaticoder/magento2-module-instantconfigurationcopy matching your minimum-stability (stable). Require it with an explicit ver
sion constraint allowing its desired stability.

require [--dev] [--prefer-source] [--prefer-dist] [--fixed] [--no-progress] [--no-suggest] [--no-update] [--no-scripts] [--update-no-dev] [--update-with-dependencies] [--update-with-all-dependencies] [--ignore-platform-reqs] [--prefer-stable] [--prefer-lowest] [--sort-packages] [-o|--optimize-autoloader] [-a|--classmap-authoritative] [--apcu-autoloader] [--skip-magento-root-plugin] [--use-default-magento-values] [--interactive-magento-conflicts] [--base-magento-edition BASE-MAGENTO-EDITION] [--base-magento-version BASE-MAGENTO-VERSION] [--] []...

This is my composer.json

```
{
"name": "anasstouaticoder/magento2-module-instantconfigurationcopy",
"description": "The InstantConfigurationCopy module provides easy way to copy configuration field hints for admin in back office Magento 2.",
"keywords": [
    "magento 2",
    "back office",
    "config hint path",
    "hint path"
],
"authors": [
    {
        "name": "Anass TOUATI",
        "email": "anass1touati@gmail.com",
        "homepage": "https://www.linkedin.com/in/anass-touati-9a3b028b/",
        "role": "Leader"
    }
],
"require": {
    "magento/framework": "*",
    "magento/module-config": "101.2.*"
},
"type": "magento2-module",
"version": "1.0.1",
"license": [
    "MIT"
],
"autoload": {
    "files": [
        "registration.php"
    ],
    "psr-4": {
        "AnassTouatiCoder\\InstantConfigurationCopy\\": ""
    }
}
```

}

should I add "minimum-stability": "dev", ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I faced same issue for hours, this is due to php version issue with composer, Try composer 1 with php 7.4 than It will work.

Comment: I found out that the package is downloadable in when using Composer 2 + php 8.1, even if I do not specify that  in my composer.json,I think packagist no longer allow newly created packages to be downloaded by composer 1 , thank you for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please refer to Magento's official documentation for instruction on hosting your package.

You can find the instruction on [link](https://developer.adobe.com/commerce/php/development/package/component/#package-and-publish-your-extension)!

Comment: yes, I did all these steps in documentation but I still got this problem, for info when I add -vvv for more details => Downloading https://packagist.org/search.json?q=anasstouaticoder/magento2-module-instantconfigurationcopy&type=

Comment: after the message I got this back trace  : Exception trace:
 () at phar:///usr/bin/composer/src/Composer/Command/InitCommand.php:782
 Composer\Command\InitCommand->findBestVersionAndNameForPackage() at phar:///usr/bin/composer/src/Composer/Command/InitCommand.php:416
 Composer\Command\InitCommand->determineRequirements() at phar:///usr/bin/composer/src/Composer/Command/RequireCommand.php:163
 Composer\Command\RequireCommand->execute() at /var/www/html/vendor/magento/composer-root-update-plugin/Plugin/Commands/OverrideRequireCommand.php:188

Comment: Can you please refer to this video as it contains step by step instructions

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4K19g6Nxnn4

Comment: If this answer works as your expected, please mark it as accepted. That indicates your issue is solved and makes it easier for others with the same issue to find a verified answer. And that would be great if you click the upvote button for the answer in case you feel it is useful.

Comment: I found out that the package is downloadable in when using Composer 2, even if I do not specify compose version in my composer.json, think it is , thank you for your help

Comment: You are welcome @lazy_coder :)